# wordpress search result page show custom category

Tags: wordpress

When using wordpress search

[.../wordpress/?s=mykeyword](https://example.com/wordpress/?s=mykeyword)

the standard search page title is

> Search Results for: mykeyword

I want the search result page behave different for search inside specific categories:

[.../wordpress/?s=mykeyword&cat=42](https://example.com/wordpress/?s=mykeyword&cat=42)

> Search Results for: mykeyword **found in Category
>   *myresolvedcategory42***

Any suggestions how to achieve that?

I have taken a look inside search.php. I need an equivalent for get_search_query() like get_search_category()

Comment: You need to modify the search form and db search query. Example on how to do https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/131805/15420  . You may need to change taxonomy to category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I assume that you are searching specifically for a category, e.g. you are implicitly allowing the user to select what categories to search through you can get the categories in a number of ways.

The best way would be to use the following and pass in your CAT parameter from the URL:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category_by_id/

This will return the name of the category with the ID given so you can add it to the title string.